# using recursion in json

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

```
{
    "_id": {
        "id": "5ba24ff"
    },
    "Istid": "4022",
    "Req": {
        "NAME": "abed"
        "class": "12"
    },
    "ackID": "738",
    "APP": "2327",
    "CUSID": "232",
}
```

code:

```
data = []
with open('Desktop/kaggle/records.json') as f:
for line in f:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
data
```

I want to access `NAME, class` specially but want to iterate through all the elements and make dataframe for each attribute in separate column like `_id, Istid, NAME, class, ackid, app, cusid`. Please help me out with recursive function in Python!

Comment: That's not the way of reading *json*. Get **all** the file contents and pass it to `json.loads`, or better: use `data = json.load(f)`, then simply `data["Req"]["NAME"]`.

Comment: there are 100 objects like that and each object has 2 attributes as above (NAME and class)..how can i iterate over entire attributes in my json  file

Comment: by converting the whole of the JSON (i.e the entire file at once) into a python array using json.loads and then looping through them

Comment: can you show me the algorithm for looping ? @ADyson

Comment: You don't know how to write a loop? BTW although your title says recursion I can't see why you would need to write anything recursive for this.

Comment: because there are nested data also inside NAME and class...so thats why recursive is best

Comment: I tried normal for loop ..its not that effective so wanted recursive

Comment: just because things are nested doesn't mean you need recursion. They're just sub-properties of the outer object. If all the objects have the same set of properties then you can simply write code to output those properties each time you loop. e.g. if in your loop you define the current item as `obj` then `obj.Req.Name` should get you the Name property within that.

Comment: okay but iam going wrong somewhere in algorithm so needed correct algo for it

Comment: Well then please show us your latest attempt at writing it. We can't guess what you did wrong.